# getting this error Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcad6.jpg)Im trying to stack the above given formula to use on my code, but i keep getting this error
Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.

I'm trying to build a graph of grouped bar chart with Deaths, recovered and Tests as seperate groups with different continents as the levels inside

Code is this:

```
 last_Day_data_graph<-lastDay_data %>%
  select(Continent, CumDeaths, CumRecovered, CumTests) %>%
  group_by(Continent)%>%
  summarise(sumCumDeaths=sum(CumDeaths), sumCumRecovered=sum(CumRecovered), sumCumTests=sum(CumTests))
last_Day_data_graph %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(sumCumDeaths, sumCumRecovered, sumCumTests),
                      names_to = "variable",
                      values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(variable, value) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = dplyr::n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(value = factor(value,levels = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Oceania", "South America"))) %>%
  ggplot(ggplot2::aes(variable, n)) +
  geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(fill = value),
                    position = "dodge",
                    stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error makes me think you have a problem with your `value` variable. But without access to your data, I can’t be sure. Please supply (at least some of) your input data using ‘dput` or `dput(head())`.

Comment: From your code I would guess that you want `Continent = factor(Continent, ...)` and `fill = Continent`.

Comment: I've attached an image above

Comment: Thank @Limey. I've attached an image in the main note

Comment: @stefan I don't know where to input that

Comment: The issue is most likely that you convert you `value` column to a factor (which will return a vector of NAs) instead of the `Continent` column, i.e. use `mutate(Continent = factor(Continent, ...)` and `geom_bar(aes(fill = Continent), ... )`.

Comment: You seem to have a solution.  That's good.  Please accept the answer if it meets your needs.  However, next time please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Alright, Thanks for the information. Didn't know that I can't do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with provided dataframe as picture:

```
df <- structure(list(Continent = c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", 
"Oceania", "South America"), sumCumDeaths = c(829L, 10864L, 42563L, 
42896L, 25L, 6198L), sumCumRecovered = c(9294L, 167396L, 165889L, 
110668L, 2935L, 42564L), sumCumTests = c(432064L, 3160072L, 7323075L, 
4803294L, 127006L, 291871L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

We have to change some things in your code. Here is a suggestion how we could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(sumCumDeaths, sumCumRecovered, sumCumTests),
                      names_to = "variable",
                      values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Continent, variable) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(variable = fct_relevel(variable, c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Oceania", 
                                            "South America"))) %>%
  ggplot(ggplot2::aes(Continent, y = log(value), fill=variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

OR another option is:

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(sumCumDeaths, sumCumRecovered, sumCumTests),
                      names_to = "variable",
                      values_to = "value") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Continent, variable) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(variable = fct_relevel(variable, c("Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Oceania", 
                                            "South America"))) %>%
  ggplot(ggplot2::aes(variable, y = log(value), fill=Continent)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]